# Extraction of specific numbers

Tags: matlab

If a string has just a combination of 1(s) and 2(s) how do you extract all the 2(s).

I have tried this code below but does not work.

```
C=textscan(trigs,'%2d.',2);
```

Could someone point me in the right direction

Comment: what exactly do you want to do after extracting the 2s? do you want to count them, print them, remove all other chars? depending on what you want to do, there are many different and easy possible commands.

Comment: `S2 = S1and2(S1and2 == '2')`

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the position of all the 2's like this:

```
str = '11221212';
strfind(str,'2')
```

Answer (score 0):

What? Just find the location of the elements in str with a '2' in it? I don't think you tried that hard, since there are at least a few ways I can see off the top of my head.

```
C = find(str == '2');
```

Or,

```
C = strfind(str,'2');
```

(There is also findstr, but that tool will apparently be obsolete/dropped at some point.)

Or,

```
C = regexp(str,'2')
```

Or,

```
C = find(ismember(str,'2'));
```

I'll bet there are lots more ways too. Take a glance through the output of this:

```
help strfun
```